# Modify the orientation of default xtick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a graph in matplotlib from a dataframe.  My dataframe has automatically populated the graph with the index name as the xlabel and has set the xtick labels as the value of each index (0-16).

But, the labels overlap each other and I can't seem to figure out how to grab them to rotate them so they will be readable.

I have tried the rotate function, but nothing changes.  So far, the only thing I've been able to do is set plt.xticks([]) and make the xticks disappear.  So, it seems like plt.xticks is in the right direction, but nothing seems to be making any changes.

```
df['Count'].plot(kind = 'bar')
df['Duration'].plot(secondary_y = True, kind = 'line', color = 'red')
width = .5

ax = plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width, len(df['Count'])-width])
plt.title('Title')
plt.ylabel('Duration (min)')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

This gives me (array([0,1,...16]), ) and then prints the graph without changing the orientation of the xticks.

The xtick labels are being set automatically (apparently), and I'm not sure how to grab them.

Comment: Your current ax is broken, it's `plt.gca()`.

Comment: I did have the () after gca. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the value of rotation angle as a parameter `rot=30` to your second plot. This will rotate the x-axis ticks with the specified angle. Use a negative value for rotating them clockwise

---

**Sample complete answer**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val':[10, 30, 20]})

df['val'].plot(kind = 'bar')
df['val'].plot(secondary_y = True, kind = 'line', color = 'red', rot=30)
```

[image]

Comment: I never even THOUGHT to try and change the X axis on that secondary plot.  I thought I would be accessing the secondary y axis there.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for this. I find this doesn't work for a histogram. I get error

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'rot'

 Any suggestions there?

Comment: @Chogg Hard to say without having the full code. Post a question and your code in a separate post